# How to average a subset of data in SAS conditional on a date?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm trying to write SAS code that can loop over a dataset that contains event dates that looks like:

```
Data event;
     input Date;
     cards;
     20200428
     20200429
     ;
run;
```

And calculate averages for the prior three-days from another dataset that contains dates and volume that looks like:

```
Data vol;
     input Date Volume;
     cards;
     20200430  100
     20200429  110
     20200428  86
     20200427  95
     20200426  80
     20200425  90
     ;
run;
```

For example, for date 20200428 the average should be 88.33 [(95+80+90)/3] and for date 20200429 the average should be 87.00 [(86+95+80)/3]. I want these values and the volume of the date to be saved on a new dataset that looks like the following if possible.

```
Data clean;
     input Date Vol Avg;
     cards;
     20200428 86 88.33
     20200429 110 87.00
     ;
run;
```

The actual data that I'm working with is from 1970-2010. I may also increase my average period from 3 days prior to 10 days prior, so I want to have flexible code. From what I've read I think a macro and/or call symput might work very well for this, but I'm not sure how to code these to do what I want. Honestly, I don't know where to start. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm open to any advice/ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Why is vol=95 in the second obs of clean?

Comment: @draycut that was an error on my part. It should be 110, not 95. My fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A SQL statement is by far the most succinct code for obtaining your result set.
The query will join with 2 independent references to volume data.  The first for obtaining the event date volume, and the second for computing the average volume over the three prior days.

The `date` data should be read in as a SAS date, so that the BETWEEN condition will be correct.

```
Data event;
     input Date: yymmdd8.;
     cards;
     20200428
     20200429
     ;
run;

Data vol;
     input Date: yymmdd8. Volume;
     cards;
     20200430  100
     20200429  110
     20200428  86
     20200427  95
     20200426  80
     20200425  90
     ;
run;
```

* SQL query with GROUP BY ;

```
proc sql;
  create table want as
  select 
    event.date
  , volume_one.volume
  , mean(volume_two.volume) as avg
  from event
  left join vol as volume_one
  on event.date = volume_one.date
  left join vol as volume_two
  on volume_two.date between event.date-1 and event.date-3
  group by 
  event.date, volume_one.volume
  ;
```

* alternative query using correlated sub-query;

```
  create table want_2 as
  select 
    event.date
  , volume
  , ( select mean(volume) as avg from vol where vol.date between event.date-1 and event.date-3 )
    as avg
  from event
  left join vol
  on event.date = vol.date
  ;
```

Comment: this code works great! Thank you so much. In my actual dataset the weekends and holidays are missing so there are gaps in the dates. Is there a way to add code to handle the possibility that the event date is on a Monday? The code should then use volume from the Wednesday, Thursday, & Friday prior instead of the Friday, Saturday, & Sunday prior to ensure that the average is accurate.

Answer (score 1):

For the case of the `Volumes` data being date gapped, a better solution would be to separately compute the rolling average of N prior volumes.  The date gaps could be from weekends, holidays, or a date not present due to data entry problems or operator error.  Conceptually, for the averaging, the only role of `date` is only to order the data.

After the rolling averages are computed, a simple `join` or `merge` can be done.

Example:

```
* Simulate some volume data that excludes weekends, holidays, and a 2% rate of missing dates;

data volumes(keep=date volume);
  call streaminit(20200502);
  do date = '01jan1970'd to today();
    length holiday $25;
    year = year(date);
    holiday = 'NEWYEAR';         hdate = holiday(holiday, year); if date=hdate then continue;
    holiday = 'USINDEPENDENCE';  hdate = holiday(holiday, year); if date=hdate then continue;
    holiday = 'THANKSGIVING';    hdate = holiday(holiday, year); if date=hdate then continue;
    holiday = 'CHRISTMAS';       hdate = holiday(holiday, year); if date=hdate then continue;
    holiday = 'MEMORIAL';        hdate = holiday(holiday, year); if date=hdate then continue;
    holiday = 'LABOR';           hdate = holiday(holiday, year); if date=hdate then continue;
    holiday = 'EASTER';          hdate = holiday(holiday, year); if date=hdate then continue;
    holiday = 'USPRESIDENTS';    hdate = holiday(holiday, year); if date=hdate then continue;

    if weekday(date) in (1,7) then continue; *1=Sun, 7=Sat;

    volume = 100 + ceil(75 * sin (date / 8));

    if rand('uniform') < 0.02 then continue;

    output;
  end;
  format date yymmdd10.;
run;
```

```
* Compute an N item rolling average from N prior values;

%let ROLLING_N = 5;

data volume_averages;

  set volumes;
  by date;      * enforce sort order requirement;

  array v[0:&ROLLING_N] _temporary_;          %* <---- &ROLLING_N ;
  retain index -1;

  avg_prior_&ROLLING_N. = mean (of v(*));     %* <---- &ROLLING_N ;

  OUTPUT;

  index = mod(index + 1,&ROLLING_N);     %* <---- Modular arithmetic, the foundation of rolling ;
  v[index] = volume;

  format v: 6.;
  drop index;
run;
```

```
* merge;

data want_merge;
  merge events(in=event_date) volume_averages;
  by date;

  if event_date;
run;

* join;

proc sql;
  create table want_join as
  select events.*, volume_averages.avg_prior_5
  from events join volume_averages
  on events.date = volume_averages.date;
quit;
```

Comment: This does exactly what I was hoping for. I was getting an error on the second block of code, but I was able to get it working by making sure the macro variable `ROLLING_N` was referenced as `&ROLLING_N.` and deleting the `%` symbols. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You want to loop over a series of dates in an input data set. Therefore I use a `PROC SQL` statement where I select the distinct dates in this input data set into a macro variable.
This macro variable is then used to loop over. In your example the macro variable will thus be: `20200428 20200429`. You can then use the `%SCAN` macro function to start looping over these dates.

For each date in the loop, we will then calculate the average: in your example the average of the 3 days prior to the looping date. As the number of days for which you want to calculate the average is variable, this is also passed as a parameter in the macro. I then use the `INTNX function` to calculate the lower bound of dates you want to select to calculate the average over. Then the `PROC MEANS` procedure is used to calculate the average volume over the days: lower bound - looping date.

I then put a minor data step in between to attach the looping date again to the calculated average. Finally everything is appended in a final data set.

```
%macro dayAverage(input = , range = , selectiondata = );

  /* Input = input dataset
     range = number of days prior to the selected date for which you want to calculate 
             the average
     selectiondata = data where the volumes are in */

  /* Create a macro variable with the dates for which you want to calculate the 
     average, to loop over */

    proc sql noprint;
      select distinct date into: datesrange separated by " "
      from &input.;
    quit;

  /*Start looping over the dates for which you want to calculate the average */

    %let I = 1;
    %do %while (%scan(&datesrange.,&I.) ne %str());

        /* Assign the current date in the loop to the variable currentdate */

        %let currentdate =  %scan(&datesrange.,&I.);

        /* Create the minimum date in the range based on input parameter range */

      %let mindate = 
      %sysfunc(putn(%sysfunc(intnx(day,%sysfunc(inputn(&currentdate.,yymmdd8.)),- 
      &range.)),yymmddn8.));

      /* Calculate the mean volume for the selected date and selected range */

      proc means data = &selectiondata.(where = (date >= &mindate. and date < 
      &currentdate.)) noprint ;
      output out  = averagecurrent(drop = _type_ _freq_) mean(volume)=avgerage_volume;
      run;

      /* Add the current date to the calculated average */

      data averagecurrent;
        retain date average_volume;
        set averagecurrent;

        date = &currentdate.;
      run;

     /* Append the result to a final list */
        proc datasets nolist;
        append base = final data = averagecurrent force;
        run;

        %let I = %eval(&I. + 1);

  %end;
 %mend;
```

This macro can in your example be called as:

```
%dayAverage(input = event, range = 3, selectiondata = vol);
```

It will give you a data set in your work library called `final`

Comment: thanks a ton for the help. I tried to run your code, but I was not able to get the desired result. In my log I received two different warnings `WARNING: Argument 1 to function INPUTN referenced by the %SYSFUNC or %QSYSFUNC macro function is out of range` and `WARNING: Variable average_volume was not found on BASE file. The variable will not be added to the BASE file. WARNING: Variable avgerage_volume was not found on DATA file.` I tried to resolve this by changing the `avgerage_volume` var to `average_volume`, but it didn't work. The output contained the same average values.